# Joomla 1.5 Internal Server Error - ways to track source

Tags: php, apache, joomla

This might be something easy, but it drives me crazy right now.
Joomla 1.5.26 -> site was running until this morning. Now I get an Internal Server Error 500 for the frontpage(html source shows nothing), backend(admin panel) works just fine.
A single editor has worked on some articles, nothing suspicious to me there.

What I have tried so far:

- Unpublished all recently created articles
- Unpublished modules with dynamic content (calendar, news feeds, recent photos)
- reset .htaccess to the original state
- reset permissions (all directories 775, all files 644)
- enabled all PHP error reporting in configuration.php (    ini_set( 'display_errors', true ); error_reporting( E_ALL ); ) - no error, just a few warinings "PHP Deprecated:  Function split()", but I can even get rid of those warings by unpublishing one plugin, after which page is still blank
- backend still works
- index.php exists and contains the original code, template exists and is assigned
- database works, no waiting processes
- deleted cache in browser as well as the Joomla cache in the backend

As I have only FTP access to the server, I cannot access any apache logfiles, except the PHP error log. What other options are there to track down such an issue? My hosting company tells me the webserver is working fine, they also told me that they have restarted the server with no changes in site behaviour.

Comment: ask them for the apache error log files (or to make them available via your ftp) nothing showed up in your php error log ?

Comment: No, nothing shows up in the error log. Thanks, I will ask them for the apache error log files.

Comment: Also check the contents of the articles updated recently (check directly in DB) look for anything odd in the article body or title that shouldn't be there such as a dodgy bit of javascript or something it could just be breaking the output rendering.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there a way to locate such output render breakers? Shouldn't such a break result in a PHP error or warning?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your host upgrades PHP and/or MySQL on the server hosting your website.

Check this post: http://www.itoctopus.com/are-you-suddenly-seeing-an-error-on-every-page-of-your-joomla-website . Your problem is most likely 2.2 (point #2, subpoint #2).

I'm pretty sure that the Apache error logs will reveal something.

Comment: Thanks, but the server software has not been touched, that's at least what the support says. However, they told me that the site was hacked two weeks ago and they set up the site from a backup then. I solved the problem now by uploading a new Joomla archive and then I reuploaded all customized files. So some of the files still must have been corrupted. I am still dissapointed that there is no stright forward way to locate the problem. Oh yes, I did not yet get access to the Apache Error log, maybe that would have helped... I think I'm going to delete this question, it's not constructive..